# Accessing Typed Value of Generic Argument in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a dispatch function which can take Payload as an argument. The Payload can be Int, String or any other type. I tried the following approaches but inside the dispatch function the payload.value is always T and not Int or String. Casting is an option but I thought that was the whole point of generics.

```
struct Payload<T> {
    let value: T
}

func dispatch<T>(payload: Payload<T>) {
    print(payload.value) // get the value as Int, String or some other type
}

let payload = Payload<Int>(value: 100)

let payload2 = Payload<String>(value: "FOO")

dispatch(payload: payload)
dispatch(payload: payload2)
```

Comment: Like you said, `T` is unconstrained, so it could be some other type. So, why is it a surprise to you that `T` is not `Int` or `String`?

Comment: So is there anyway to get the value as Int. One way I can think is casting to Int or String or any other type.

Comment: As you said, "that was the whole point of generics". You are not supposed to know what `T` actually is. If you really need to know, then this is a misuse of generics.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know T is unconstrained so it can be any type. Your only option is to cast the value to the types you are expecting. You can simply switch the value:

```
switch payload.value {
case let value as Int:
    print("Int:", value)
case let value as String:
    print("String:", value)
default:
    print("some other type", payload.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to get inside your `dispatch`, you can create a protocol and requires T to be conformed to that protocol.

```
protocol Printable {
    func printValue() -> String
}

struct Payload<T> {
    let value: T
}

func dispatch<T: Printable>(payload: Payload<T>) {
    print(payload.value.printValue()) // get the value as Int, String or some other type
}

extension String: Printable {
    func printValue() -> String {
        return self
    }
}

extension Int: Printable {
    func printValue() -> String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}
```

Comment: There is already a protocol that both types conform to `CustomStringConvertible` creating another one is pointless

Comment: I wanted that when Payload(value: 100) then payload.value is Int and when Payload(value: "FFF") then payload.value is String

Comment: @LeoDabus as I've said, it depends on your need. The above is just an idea about how we can use protocols to do. Of course, in reality the protocol is definitely not that simple.

Comment: @johndoe You can't do that because T is a value of 1 and only 1 type. And I think what you want to achieve is not what generic is invented to do. Therefore, you have no option but to cast to concrete types.